# Linking the href value from an <a> tag to another html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 html pages. The first page holds the links and once the user clicks on one link, then it redirects to the second page. What I am trying to achieve though is to have the href value at the top of the second page once the user clicks one of the links.

At the moment, I have a function that gets the href value, but when I go to the second page I get an error on the console "Cannot read property href of null".

What am I missing to get this behaviour? I enclose my code for more information

1. The html for the link (Link.html)

   ```
   <body>
       <a href="ApplicationForm.html" id="linkId" onclick="getLinkValue()">Link</a>
   </body>
   ```
2. The script that gets the href value (AppInit.js)

   ```
       function getLinkValue() {
           var linkValue = document.getElementById("linkId").href;
           return linkValue;
       };
   ```
3. The html page that the href value should be displayed(ApplicationForm.html)

   ```
     <button type="button" name="button" onclick="displayLinkValue();">Get href value</button>
     <div id="container">
             <!-- The container that should include the href value from the previous page -->
     </div>
   ```
4. The script that is supposed to get the link value from AppInit (This is a different js file)

   ```
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src ="AppInit.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
   function displayLinkValue() {
       var linkContainer = document.getElementById('container');
       linkContainer.innerHTML += getLinkValue();
   };
   ```

Comment: I don't understand this. You link to a target page, but that target page knows very well which page it is. It doesn't need the original page to tell it that...  Please clarify? Secondly, code blocks are best formatted with 4 spaces, not with backticks on each line.

Comment: These are two different scripts, The one is called AppInit.js and the second one is a different js file. So I'm targeting the AppInit on the other js file. Apologies for that - should have been clearer in my question

Comment: I still don't get it. The *HTML page* of step three is the *ApplicationForm.html* from step one, right? But *ApplicationForm.html* knows very well it is called that... why a complex script to tell *"Hey I am ApplicationForm.html"*. I probably miss some clue in your question.

Comment: Nope, these are still two different html files and the point is to link the href value from step 1 to the div in step 3. I will make one more edit on that as well.

Comment: I understood they are two HTML files. Let's say A and B. A has a href pointing to B. You want to show the href value on page B, but that href value **IS** B, no!? How else could it point to B?

Comment: Yes, it has the value of B, but because I will have a generic Application Forrm, I want to have a reference on the top. That reference will be the href value, the value attribute or just the text between the <a> tags ("Software developer" say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be thinking that the value stored in step two in the variable *linkValue* can be retrieved in a later step after having navigated, but this is not the case.

JavaScript variables only retain their values during the life of the web page. Once you navigate to another page, you start from scratch again.

To retain values you need to either pass them on when you navigate via URL parameters (or POST), or persist them (cookies, *localStorage*, ...).

In your case, I would suggest URL parameters:

1. Link.html

   Add an URL argument which needs a name (e.g. *arg*) and a value (e.g. *ApplicationForm*):

   ```
   <body>
       <a href="ApplicationForm.html?arg=ApplicationForm">
          Link
       </a>
   </body>
   ```
2. ApplicationForm.html

   ```
   <div id="container"></div>

   <script>
   // function to get a particular argument from the URL
   function getUrlArg(name) {
       var res = location.search.substr(1).split("&").filter(function (item) {
           return item.indexOf(name + '=') === 0;
       }).pop();
       return res ? decodeURIComponent(res.substr(res.indexOf('=') + 1)) : '';
   }

   document.getElementById('container').textContent = getUrlArg('arg');
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your illuminating comments and code samples. That seems to work, even though I have to go through it and understand the concept. Thanks again